# custom rewrites with apache's mod_proxy and mod_proxy_balancer

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I currently have 2 application server nodes behind an apache mod_proxy+mod_balancer load balancer . I am about to deploy a third server, but I want to do a quick test on it. Is there a way I can have my load balancer redirect only my workstation's static IP address to the third node for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was making it to complicated. I simply edited my /etc/hosts to point directly to the new server's IP address.